# Expanding CSS shape with text

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I've been working on trying to get this CSS shape to expand with text and I am not sure if it's even possible since the text is `position:absolute;` above (or in front rather) of the CSS shape.

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/W2SPd/10/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rearranged your CSS: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W2SPd/13/)

Basically it involves removing the `position:absolute` and fixed width, and instead allowing a dynamic with (using `display:inline-block`) and moving the text into place with `position:relative` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved used pseudo elements, allowing you to only have to use a single div element:

```css
div{
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
  background:tomato;
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  }
div:before, div:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;  
  border-top:50px solid tomato;
  }
div:before{
  left:-50px;
  border-left:50px solid transparent;
  }

div:after{
  right:-50px;
  border-right:50px solid transparent;
  }
```

```html
<div>This is text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the span CSS style as below:

**CSS**

```
h1 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -78px;
  width: 111px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W2SPd/182/)